# BODMAS calculation in c

Tags: c

Hi i m trying to write a code in C to solve the mathematical equation based on BODMAS rule,any suggestion?
for eg:
the program should give the output as:
(8+8)/2+4=12

Comment: A suggestion for what, specifically?

Comment: Suggestion: don't use C.

Comment: http://www.lawrence.edu/fast/greggj/CMSC270/Infix.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calc(char *exp_str){
    FILE *fp;
    int ret;
    fp=fopen("calc_aux.c","w");
    fprintf(fp, "int main(){ return %s; }", exp_str);
    fclose(fp);
    system("gcc calc_aux.c -o calc_aux.exe");
    ret=system("calc_aux.exe");
    remove("calc_aux.c");
    remove("calc_aux.exe");
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    char exp[]="(8+8)/2+4";
    printf("%s=%d\n", exp, calc(exp));
}
//result:(8+8)/2+4=12
```

Comment: thnx it worked,but can u write the comment as well so that i could be more clear how the program is functioning

Comment: @AshishKarna , Please look at the comment is also linked to calc function.